# Is there any elegant way to create irregular DatetimeIndex?

Tags: pandas, python-datetime

Suppose that I have a list of trading dates: `[20180104, 20180105, 20180108, 20180109]`. There are two trading periods for each day: `[09:30, 11:30]` and `[13:00, 15:00]`. And I want to create a `pd.DatetimeIndex` include all trading intervals of frequency 30 minutes and closed by right, i.e. the result will be:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-04 10:00:00', '2018-01-04 10:30:00',
               '2018-01-04 11:00:00', '2018-01-04 11:30:00',
               '2018-01-04 13:30:00', '2018-01-04 14:00:00',
               '2018-01-04 14:30:00', '2018-01-04 15:00:00',
               '2018-01-05 10:00:00', '2018-01-05 10:30:00',
               '2018-01-05 11:00:00', '2018-01-05 11:30:00',
               '2018-01-05 13:30:00', '2018-01-05 14:00:00',
               '2018-01-05 14:30:00', '2018-01-05 15:00:00',
               '2018-01-08 10:00:00', '2018-01-08 10:30:00',
               '2018-01-08 11:00:00', '2018-01-08 11:30:00',
               '2018-01-08 13:30:00', '2018-01-08 14:00:00',
               '2018-01-08 14:30:00', '2018-01-08 15:00:00',
               '2018-01-09 10:00:00', '2018-01-09 10:30:00',
               '2018-01-09 11:00:00', '2018-01-09 11:30:00',
               '2018-01-09 13:30:00', '2018-01-09 14:00:00',
               '2018-01-09 14:30:00', '2018-01-09 15:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Here is my solution, but I am not satisfied with it：

```
In [17]: import pandas as pd
In [18]: dates = pd.to_datetime([20180104, 20180105, 20180108, 20180109], format='%Y%m%d')
In [19]: delta1 = pd.timedelta_range('9H30Min', '11H30Min', freq='30Min', closed='right')
In [20]: delta2 = pd.timedelta_range('13H', '15H', freq='30Min', closed='right')

In [21]: index = None
In [22]: for date in dates:
    ...:     for delta in [delta1, delta2]:
    ...:         if index is None:
    ...:             index = date + delta
    ...:         else:
    ...:             index = index.append(date + delta)
    ...:             

In [23]: index
Out[23]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-04 10:00:00', '2018-01-04 10:30:00',
               '2018-01-04 11:00:00', '2018-01-04 11:30:00',
               '2018-01-04 13:30:00', '2018-01-04 14:00:00',
...
```

Is there any more elegant way to solve this question? (ideally, without for loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
idx=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([dates,delta1.append(delta2)])
idx.get_level_values(0)+idx.get_level_values(1)

Out[441]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-04 10:00:00', '2018-01-04 10:30:00',
               '2018-01-04 11:00:00', '2018-01-04 11:30:00',
               '2018-01-04 13:30:00', '2018-01-04 14:00:00',
               '2018-01-04 14:30:00', '2018-01-04 15:00:00',
               '2018-01-05 10:00:00', '2018-01-05 10:30:00',
               '2018-01-05 11:00:00', '2018-01-05 11:30:00',
               '2018-01-05 13:30:00', '2018-01-05 14:00:00',
               '2018-01-05 14:30:00', '2018-01-05 15:00:00',
               '2018-01-08 10:00:00', '2018-01-08 10:30:00',
               '2018-01-08 11:00:00', '2018-01-08 11:30:00',
               '2018-01-08 13:30:00', '2018-01-08 14:00:00',
               '2018-01-08 14:30:00', '2018-01-08 15:00:00',
               '2018-01-09 10:00:00', '2018-01-09 10:30:00',
               '2018-01-09 11:00:00', '2018-01-09 11:30:00',
               '2018-01-09 13:30:00', '2018-01-09 14:00:00',
               '2018-01-09 14:30:00', '2018-01-09 15:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution is very elegant and about 20x faster than mine.

Comment: @Eastsun yw~ :-) happy coding